# How to display both portrait & landscape images into a square on the grid without disturbing the aspect ratio?

Tags: image, qt, gridview, qml, image-gallery

I am using a `GridView` to create a **gallery** of images that I display from a certain folder on my machine. The **images are of different width*height ratios**. Few are portrait images where the height of the image is like 3 times more than width. Some image are landscape like where the width is approx 3 times of height. And some images are squared.

**The issue** with my gallery is I have a square for each `Image` component of my `GridView` as you can see below. This makes the portrait & landscape images get incorrectly stretched as each block in the Grid is a square. Thus causing the aspect ratio of the image to get skewed up.

**The Question:**
How can I ensure that I display both portrait & landscape images into my square without skewing the aspect ratio? I am looking at putting some black/grey background on parts of the square which go blank on a portrait or landscape image? But there might be other tricks.

**The code:**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQml.Models 2.1

GridView {
  cellHeight: height/2
  cellWidth: width/2
  clip: true

  FolderListModel {
    id: dir_model
    folder: "/path/to/images/folder"
    nameFilters: ["*.png"]
  }

  Component {
    id: file_delegate

    Image {
        width: (parent.width)/2
        height: (parent.width)/2
        source: fileURL
    }
  }

  model: dir_model
  delegate: file_delegate
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit` on Image ?

Comment: perfect. thats what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `Image` [fillMode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#fillMode-prop) property to `Image.PreserveAspectFit`
As the doc says:

> the image is scaled uniformly to fit without cropping